# Interface for accessing to guest OS via libvirt

Tags: linux, virtualization, libvirt, lxc, guest

Is there any possible (not necessary native) ways to get access (e.g., terminal usage is the main purpose for me) to guest OS with `*nix` using `libvirt`/`LXC`(not as libvirt module) capabilities? And I don't mean to use methods like `lxc-console` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the guest is set up with a serial console, you can use `virsh console`. This works well with kvm, never tried it with LXC though

To access the serial console directly, without libvirt:
Add this to the qemu-kvm cmd line

```
-chardev socket,id=monitor,path=/srv/kvm/${VMNAME}/run/monitor.sock,server,nowait \
-monitor chardev:monitor \
-chardev socket,id=serial0,path=/srv/kvm/${VMNAME}/run/console.sock,server,nowait \
-serial chardev:serial0
```

I pointed the socket to /srv/kvm/VMNAME/run in this case
Then you can use `minicom`

```
cd /srv/kvm/VMNAME/run
minicom -D unix\#console.sock
```

On most distributions, you also need to have `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8` or something similar in the kernel boot line

Comment: In my question, I mean is there any some other ways to do the same as `virsh console`? Or it's impossible?

Comment: You can do what libvirt does manually, through the sockets qemu has. But if you are using libvirt already, why bother?

Comment: I just need to know all possible ways for my project. Can u link on proper functions, that can do the same as `virsh console`?

Comment: see the post update

Answer (score 0):

`virsh domdisplay <VM-name>` will give you a URL for connecting to a graphical console for a guest, if the guest doesn't have a serial console enabled.

`virsh console <VM-name>` will connect to the guest's serial console.

If all of this command line crap just annoys you, install the `virt-manager` GUI and you can point and click your way around managing your guests. (Note that `virt-manager` cannot yet *install* LXC guests.)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a private network that is not accessible outside the LXC-server and use that network to access the LXC-guests via SSH (and bind SSH only to that network within the LXC guest).